# Filter out arrays of a 2d Array that can be made from other arrays in that 2D array

Tags: javascript, optimization, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming

So, say we have an array of arrays, arr
arr = [[1], [3], [1, 3]]
Now, we want to find a subset of arr that will filter out any arrays whose elements can all be found in other arrays, optimizing for the least number of arrays in the output. In the above case, we'd get [[1, 3]]. Now, this is not too hard, but I'd like for it to be able to scale. Say, if I were to have 60 arrays, each with up to 70 elements.

Here is my attempt at a solution:

const x = [[1], [3], [1, 3]]
recursiveFindShortestSolution(x, x.flat())

```
function recursiveFindShortestSolution(array, allElements){
    if(array.length === 0){
        return null
    }
    if(!oneArrayContainsAll2DArray(allElements, array)){
        return null
    }
    let solution = array
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        const childSolution = recursiveFindShortestSolution([...array.slice(0, i), ...array.slice(i+1)], allElements)
        if(childSolution){
            solution = childSolution
        }
    }
    return solution
}

function oneArrayContainsAll2DArray(oneDArray, twoDArray){
    const flatTwoDArray = twoDArray.flat()
    if(oneDArray.every((element)=>{
        return flatTwoDArray.includes(element)
    })){
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Now, obviously, this takes ages to run on something as complex as I need. I know that dynamic programming should help me optimize, but I just get heap overflow. If anybody has any. optimization tips, that would be appreciated. Here is my test data:

```
[
  [ 32, 33 ],
  [ 34, 32, 35, 33 ],
  [ 36, 32, 37, 33 ],
  [ 40, 32, 41, 33 ],
  [ 48, 32, 49, 33 ],
  [ 96, 32, 97, 33 ],
  [ 162, 34, 163, 35 ],
  [ 224, 96, 225, 97 ],
  [ 191, 63, 183, 55 ],
  [ 239, 111, 231, 103 ],
  [
    38, 34, 36, 32,
    39, 35, 37, 33
  ],
  [
    42, 34, 40, 32,
    43, 35, 41, 33
  ],
  [
    44, 36, 40, 32,
    45, 37, 41, 33
  ],
  [
    50, 34, 48, 32,
    51, 35, 49, 33
  ],
  [
    52, 36, 48, 32,
    53, 37, 49, 33
  ],
  [
    56, 40, 48, 32,
    57, 41, 49, 33
  ],
  [
    98, 34, 96, 32,
    99, 35, 97, 33
  ],
  [
    100, 36, 96, 32,
    101, 37, 97, 33
  ],
  [
    104, 40, 96, 32,
    105, 41, 97, 33
  ],
  [
    112, 48, 96, 32,
    113, 49, 97, 33
  ],
  [
    166, 38, 162, 34,
    167, 39, 163, 35
  ],
  [
    170, 42, 162, 34,
    171, 43, 163, 35
  ],
  [
    178, 50, 162, 34,
    179, 51, 163, 35
  ],
  [
    226, 98, 162, 34,
    227, 99, 163, 35
  ],
  [
    228, 100, 224, 96,
    229, 101, 225, 97
  ],
  [
    240, 112, 224, 96,
    241, 113, 225, 97
  ],
  [
    174, 46, 166, 38,
    170, 42, 162, 34
  ],
  [
    248, 120, 240,
    112, 249, 121,
    241, 113
  ],
  [
    255, 127, 191, 63,
    247, 119, 183, 55
  ],
  [
    46, 38, 42, 34, 44, 36,
    40, 32, 47, 39, 43, 35,
    45, 37, 41, 33
  ],
  [
    54, 38, 50, 34, 52, 36,
    48, 32, 55, 39, 51, 35,
    53, 37, 49, 33
  ],
  [
    58, 42, 50, 34, 56, 40,
    48, 32, 59, 43, 51, 35,
    57, 41, 49, 33
  ],
  [
    60, 44, 52, 36, 56, 40,
    48, 32, 61, 45, 53, 37,
    57, 41, 49, 33
  ],
  [
    102, 38,  98, 34, 100, 36,
     96, 32, 103, 39,  99, 35,
    101, 37,  97, 33
  ],
  [
    106, 42,  98, 34, 104, 40,
     96, 32, 107, 43,  99, 35,
    105, 41,  97, 33
  ],
  [
    108, 44, 100, 36, 104, 40,
     96, 32, 109, 45, 101, 37,
    105, 41,  97, 33
  ],
  [
    114, 50,  98, 34, 112, 48,
     96, 32, 115, 51,  99, 35,
    113, 49,  97, 33
  ],
  [
    116, 52, 100, 36, 112, 48,
     96, 32, 117, 53, 101, 37,
    113, 49,  97, 33
  ],
  [
    120, 56, 104, 40, 112, 48,
     96, 32, 121, 57, 105, 41,
    113, 49,  97, 33
  ],
  [
    182, 54, 166, 38, 178, 50,
    162, 34, 183, 55, 167, 39,
    179, 51, 163, 35
  ],
  [
    186, 58, 170, 42, 178, 50,
    162, 34, 187, 59, 171, 43,
    179, 51, 163, 35
  ],
  [
    230, 102, 166,  38, 226,
     98, 162,  34, 231, 103,
    167,  39, 227,  99, 163,
     35
  ],
  [
    234, 106, 170,  42, 226,
     98, 162,  34, 235, 107,
    171,  43, 227,  99, 163,
     35
  ],
  [
    242, 114, 178,  50, 226,
     98, 162,  34, 243, 115,
    179,  51, 227,  99, 163,
     35
  ],
  [
    244, 116, 228, 100, 240,
    112, 224,  96, 245, 117,
    229, 101, 241, 113, 225,
     97
  ],
  [
    190, 62, 174, 46, 182, 54,
    166, 38, 186, 58, 170, 42,
    178, 50, 162, 34
  ],
  [
    238, 110, 174,  46, 230,
    102, 166,  38, 234, 106,
    170,  42, 226,  98, 162,
     34
  ],
  [
    252, 124, 244, 116,
    248, 120, 240, 112,
    253, 125, 245, 117,
    249, 121, 241, 113
  ],
  [
    246, 118, 182,  54, 230, 102, 166,
     38, 242, 114, 178,  50, 226,  98,
    162,  34, 247, 119, 183,  55, 231,
    103, 167,  39, 243, 115, 179,  51,
    227,  99, 163,  35
  ],
  [
    250, 122, 186,  58, 234, 106, 170,
     42, 242, 114, 178,  50, 226,  98,
    162,  34, 251, 123, 187,  59, 235,
    107, 171,  43, 243, 115, 179,  51,
    227,  99, 163,  35
  ],
  [
    254, 126, 190,  62, 238, 110, 174,
     46, 246, 118, 182,  54, 230, 102,
    166,  38, 250, 122, 186,  58, 234,
    106, 170,  42, 242, 114, 178,  50,
    226,  98, 162,  34
  ],
  [
    126,  62, 110,  46, 118,  54, 102,  38, 122,  58, 106,
     42, 114,  50,  98,  34, 124,  60, 108,  44, 116,  52,
    100,  36, 120,  56, 104,  40, 112,  48,  96,  32, 127,
     63, 111,  47, 119,  55, 103,  39, 123,  59, 107,  43,
    115,  51,  99,  35, 125,  61, 109,  45, 117,  53, 101,
     37, 121,  57, 105,  41, 113,  49,  97,  33
  ]
]
```

Comment: There are optimizations such as immediately deciding you need subarrays whose numbers do not appear in any other subarray. But, the extent of the brute-force search for the non-optimizable cases is so huge that I think you'll probably have to settle for "pretty good" instead of perfect, and not cover all possibilities

Answer (score 0):

You can use functional approach with `reduce()` and `filter()` methods using few helper functions. The `filterSubsets` function uses `reduce` to create a new array. It checks if an tested sub-array is unique, if so it adds it  to the accumulated array. Then the result array is filtered to exclude any arrays that are subsets of other arrays.

```js
const arr = [[1], [3], [1, 3]];


// check if arr1 is a subset of arr2
const isSubset = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.every(elem => arr2.includes(elem));

// check if arr1 is equal to arr2
const isEqual = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.length === arr2.length && arr1.every((elem, idx) => elem === arr2[idx]);

// check if arr1 is unique
const isUnique = (arr1, arrList) => !arrList.some(existingArr => isEqual(arr1, existingArr) || isSubset(arr1, existingArr));

// returns arrays that are not subsets of any other arrays
const filterSubsets = (arrList) =>
  arrList.reduce((acc, arr) => (isUnique(arr, acc) ? acc.concat([arr]) : acc), [])
         .filter((arr, index, arrList) =>
           !arrList.some((superArr, superIndex) => superIndex !== index && isSubset(arr, superArr)));

console.log(filterSubsets(arr));
```

Comment: This approach fails with the input `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]]`

Comment: Thanks for answering, but Andrew is correct. I need not only to find if an array is a subset of another array, but if it consists of elements of other arrays. Doing this iteratively is trivial, but I'm looking for an optimized solution